# How to get a div from an iframe?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a way to delete the following `highlighted` div:

[image]

I can get the `div` width:

```js
document.querySelector("#root > main > div:nth-child(2) > div > form > div > p")
```

But I don't understand why, but the above only works after I `inspect` the page at least once, when I reload it didn't catch the `div` anymore, probably because it's inside of an `iframe`?

The picture is from this page: https://docs.widgetbot.io/
and the highlighted div is from the discord widget icon at the bottom.

I'm asking this because I'm using the widget in my qt app and I would like to delete the div to disable people trying to send messages through it.

Would like to ask how I could dynamically delete this `div`

Comment: The point of a shadow root is such that the outer script cannot modify its contents.

Answer (score 0):

So , you can get the content from iframe using javascript easily using

iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

Also you can use other methods too..

then simply iterate the elements or find using class or id ..

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you give an example? when i get the iframe it doesn't show any element `document.querySelector('widgetbot-crate > crate > div').shadowRoot.querySelector('iframe')`